# Filter in R if there is any value in row between range

Tags: r, filter

I have this `data.frame`

```
V1      V2      V3      V4      V5
<dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   1.000
0.651   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.349
0.000   0.000   1.000   0.000   0.000
0.703   0.000   0.297   0.000   0.000
0.018   0.982   0.000   0.000   0.000
0.683   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.317
0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   1.000
0.000   0.000   0.000   0.000   1.000
0.000   0.001   0.000   0.000   0.999
```

Where the columns are probabilities of membership in a given class. I need to filter the rows that have any values between a given range, say `.30 > x > .70`.

Desirable outcome would be

```
V1      V2      V3      V4      V5
<dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
0.651   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.349
0.683   0.000   0.000   0.000   0.317
```

I tried `data %>% filter(if_any(starts_with("V"), ~ . > 0.3) & if_any(starts_with("V"), ~ . < 0.7))` but that returns pretty much all the rows.

Comment: The logic should be `df %>% filter(if_any(starts_with("V"), ~ .x > 0.3 & .x < 0.7))`

Answer (score 1):

You could `rowwise` filter across all columns and check your conditions like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(any(c_across() > 0.3 & c_across() < 0.7))

#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#> # Rowwise: 
#>      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 0.651     0     0     0 0.349
#> 2 0.683     0     0     0 0.317
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Note that rowwise operations are inefficient when the data is large. `if_any` is more recommended here.